# Using Node.js for Point Of Sales System

Tags: node.js

I've been thinking about nodejs lately and i'm wondering if i can use node.js for a huge Point Of Sales application project but it got me thinking if is it a good idea to use node.js for this job? can a POS system considered as a blocking application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think NodeJs is a good choice for POS because this system is not CPU intensive, instead, its data intensive. This means that you do not need to perform heavy processing and complex formulas on transactions, instead your application will receive a transaction, will perform some basic operations, and will place it in the database. NodeJS is good for that. If you use NodeJs with [Quasar](https://quasar.dev/) it will save a lot of your development time because you only have to write your application one time and then using Quasar you can make Cross-Platform Desktop App from it (using ElectronJS), Mobile app (using Cordova), and a Web app.